# AngularJS - Changing order on ng-click?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

quick question.

I have an ng-repeat, and I know I can use orderBy to change the order of them, but I would like to have it so that if someone clicks on one it swaps it with the repeated one next to it. Here is an example of what I'm trying to do in pseudocode:

```
    <div ng-repeat="object in objects" 
    ng-click="swap position of object with the object next to it"></div>
```

Is this possible? I'm having trouble even figuring out the logic of what I would do behind it. I'm thinking maybe getting the distance from $first and then subtracting one from it? I'm really confused. I'd really appreciate it if someone could help  me out.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Can you include more information?  There's a bunch of different ways this can be done, depending on where the data is held, what kind of data it is, how many objects are being displayed, etc.  It'll be easier to give a more definite answer if you can give more details.

Comment: set `orderBy sortorder`, and then in the `ng-click` change the `sortorder`. Or you could actually splice out the item and change the order in the actual array (which I'm guessing `objects` is)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by switching the position in the array. Here's the function I used:

```
 $scope.move = function (arr, old_index, new_index) {
    if (new_index >= arr.length) {
        var k = new_index - arr.length;
        while ((k--) + 1) {
            arr.push(undefined);
        }
    }
    arr.splice(new_index, 0, arr.splice(old_index, 1)[0]);
    return arr;
};
```

Maybe this will help someone!